# Jquery -> How to select ID with same name as class by click on class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a li with classname "gallery1 multgalerie" and after click on it I want to show div with id "gallery1" (and 2, 3, 4...). So the meaning of the code looks like this:

```
$( ".conty li" ).click(function() {

var className = $(this).attr('class');

$('.conty li').css('font-weight', '400');
$(this).css('font-weight', '600');

$('.multgalerie').slideUp();
$(#className).slideDown();

});
```

So the question is how to use this **$(#className).slideDown();** ,select ID, properly, since it has same ID name as class clicked bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use:

```
$("#"+className).slideDown();
```

Pay attention you are using multi classes , this will return a list.

This sample code shows what i mean:

```
//Get list of CSS class names
        var classNames = $("#myDiv").attr("class").split(' ');
        $.each(classNames, function (i, className) {
            alert(className);
        });
```

Comment: @dersvenhesse yeah i know , i meant a list of classes like multiple names not only a single name.

Comment: $("#"+className).slideDown(); This works great and its everything i was looking for :) I got only one class on li, so its ok with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use classes for this purpose. Using classes as data attributes will slow down the actual CSS processing for no real advantage.

Instead use `data-` attributes to hold metadata such as related elements. That is what they are there for.

Your element could have the entire selector in a `data-` attribute

e.g.

`class="multgalerie" data-gallery="#gallery1"`

and the code would change to:

```
$( ".conty li" ).click(function() {
    var gallery = $(this).data('gallery');
    [snip]    
    $(gallery).slideDown();
});
```